How to limit/cap values exceeding a certain value in Notepad++
I have this snippet of code in yml:
      - Item: Oldman's_Romance
        Rate: 50
      - Item: Grasshopper's_Leg
        Rate: 8000
      - Item: Azure_Jewel
        Rate: 9000
      - Item: Grasshopper_Doll
        Rate: 1500
      - Item: Angel's_Arrival
        Rate: 1000
      - Item: Center_Potion
        Rate: 700

I want to change the values of "Rate" to be capped at 5000.
It would look something like this:
      - Item: Oldman's_Romance
        Rate: 50
      - Item: Grasshopper's_Leg
        Rate: 5000
      - Item: Azure_Jewel
        Rate: 5000
      - Item: Grasshopper_Doll
        Rate: 1500
      - Item: Angel's_Arrival
        Rate: 1000
      - Item: Center_Potion
        Rate: 700


If I understood correctly, what you want is to replace all the Rate's that are above 5000 and change them into 5000.
I think that what you could do is search for
Rate: [5-9]\d{3}
And replace to
Rate: 5000
Explanation:

Rate:  I think this doesnt need explanation
[5-9] five to nine
\d Digits (zero to nine)
{3} Has three digits

So basically, lets search for strings that has Rate:  followed up by a number that must be five to nine, and then other 3 digits
Note: this only works for numbers above 5000 and below or equal 9999

You can replace matches of the regular expression
(?<=\bRate: )(?:[5-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4,})\b

Demo
The expression can be broken down as follows.
(?<=\bRate: )   # positive lookbehind asserts that the match
                # is immediately preceded by a word boundary
                # followed by 'Rate: '
(?:             # begin a non-capture group
  [5-9]\d{3}    # match a digit `5` to `9` followed by 3 digits 
|               # or
  [1-9]\d{4,}   # match a digit `1` to `9` followed by 4 or more digits
)               # end non-capture group
\b              # match a word boundary

